# View source not displaying dynamic content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am making very simple next js application, where everything is working fine but except the view source.

I am making a promise and there is a delay in retrieving content and after when those content loaded and if I view source (ctrl + u) in chrome, I couldn't get those dynamic content loaded in the source.

So it is reproduceable in the link,

**Step 1)** Just click on the codesandbox link: https://3re10.sse.codesandbox.io

[image]

**Step 2)** After that choose view source (ctrl + u), and it gives page like,

[image]

Here you could clearly see that there is **no** element with text `My name is Jared` and all other text which is intended to be there but it is not.

Only `Loading...` text is available in page source which comes on page load.

The entire application working code is available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-typescript-template-u8evx

Please help me how could I reflect all the dynamic content in view source in Next Js application.

I could understand that this is due to behaviour of **async** .. But really I couldn't understand the way to overcome this and display the dynamic content once loaded.. Please help me, I am stuck with this for very long..

A big thanks in advance..

Comment: What is your goal? do you need to prerender user information on the server?

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev, I just need to get all the information in the page while doing view page source.. Now you can see it only see ```Loading...``` and not all the dynamic content rendered later.. I am sorry that I am new to Next Js and hence I don't know exact term but requirement is I should get all the content that comes from API/ Promise as well in the view page source..

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev, May be your sentence is what I want I believe..

Comment: Please add https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to the question itself as those codesandbox links are not permanent.

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev, As I am new into Next, I don't know to add next js snippet in stackoverflow.. But for now forgive and help me with the codesandbox please..

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev, Also in my real application I am not using anything like ```useSWR``` , I just got a codesandbox like that with working to reproduced issue.. In real application I am using class component and using javascript fetch to fetch the api..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev, As I believe the codesandbox would give better picture and I am stucked with this for long time, I made in such a way.. I can get your point for now I am in the help of achieving the result ASAP with at least the sandbox link.. So I hope you understand my situation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're explicitly telling React to fetch a user on a client-side.

```
function Profile() {
  const { data, revalidate } = useSWR("/api/user", fetch);
}
```

If you need to prerender a user info on the server you can do it with one of the following functions:

- getStaticProps (Static Generation): Fetch data at **build** time
- getServerSideProps (Server-side Rendering): Fetch data on **each request**.

As you fetching a user info, I assume that it should be requested on each request, so use `getServerSideProps`.

```
const URL = 'api/user/'

export default function Profile({ initialData }) {
  const { data } = useSWR(URL, fetcher, { initialData })

  return (
    // render 
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const data = await fetcher(URL)
  return { props: { initialData: data } }
}
```

This way you would fetch a user info on the server and give it to React with first render. Also, you would have `useSWR` on a client side that will periodically revalidate data.

Suggested reading:
[Data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is it possible for you to modify the working example link provided,  https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-typescript-template-u8evx with your solution which would be better for understanding..

Comment: I hope now you would better understand my problem here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61092593/12856847

Answer (score 0):

If you use nextjs you must run
`yarn build`
and
`yarn export`
then you have directory 'out' with your exported static content.

Because now your example is CSR (client side rendering)

Comment: What is the need to run these comments ```yarn build``` and ```yarn export``` ?? My only requirement is it should display the dynamic content as well in page source..

Comment: "Because now your example is CSR (client side rendering)" Then how should I make it the dynamic content visible at while doing view source.. Can you modify the example link provided and make the dynamic content visible in page source which would be helpful for me to understand..

Answer (score 0):

Other answers already quite clear telling you the reason why your dynamic content doesn't appear on source code.

First, there are two kinds of rendering: **server side** and **client side**.

- ***Server side / SSR*** is when your server render your app and then send it to the client (browser).
- ***Client side / CSR*** is when your app reach the browser, it will be rendered again (but this time only render what is necessary if you have activated SSR, which NextJS has as default).

If you want your dynamic content to be appear at the source code, you should call your api on the **server side** like `@Nikolai Kiselev` has mentioned.
NextJS provides function ***getServerSideProps()***(for the component level) to be used if developers want to fetch info on the **server side**.

If you put your profile() function as a **page**, you could also use ***getInitialProps()*** function to fetch your api from server side.

Please take a look on NextJS doc, they have given the examples you need.